# Difference between StandardTokenizerFactory and KeywordTokenizerFactory in Solr?

Tags: java, solr, solrnet, tokenize

I am new to Solr.I want to know when to use **StandardTokenizerFactory** and **KeywordTokenizerFactory**?

I read the docs on Apache Wiki, but I am not getting it.

Can anybody explain the **difference between StandardTokenizerFactory and KeywordTokenizerFactory**?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

StandardTokenizerFactory :-
It tokenizes on whitespace, as well as strips characters

Documentation :-

> Splits words at punctuation characters, removing punctuations.
>   However, a dot that's not followed by whitespace is considered part of
>   a token.   Splits words at hyphens, unless there's a number in the
>   token. In that case, the whole token is interpreted as a product
>   number and is not split.   Recognizes email addresses and Internet
>   hostnames as one token.

Would use this for fields where you want to search on the field data.

e.g. -

```
http://example.com/I-am+example?Text=-Hello
```

would generate 7 tokens (separated by comma) -

```
http,example.com,I,am,example,Text,Hello
```

KeywordTokenizerFactory :-

Keyword Tokenizer does not split the input at all.
No processing in performed on the string, and the whole string is treated as a single entity.
This doesn't actually do any tokenization. It returns the original text as one term.

Mainly used for sorting or faceting requirements, where you want to match the exact facet when filtering on multiple words and sorting as sorting does not work on tokenized fields.

e.g.

```
http://example.com/I-am+example?Text=-Hello
```

would generate a single token -

```
http://example.com/I-am+example?Text=-Hello
```

Comment: StandardTokenizerFactory doesn't split on all punctuation, for example a word containing an apostrophe (eg `can't` `won't` etc) will be left in tact.

Comment: yup. as mentioned it does not split on all special chars or strip all special chars. It has certain rules.

Comment: I noticed `KeywordTokenizerFactory ` performance is poor (not giving the search results quickly) when compared to `StandardTokenizerFactory`. What would be the best way to improve performance (search results) on `KeywordTokenizerFactory `?